# When will "permuted vectors" be linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, fourier-transform, linear-independence

Let $n\geq2$ be a natural number and let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be $n$ real numbers.  Is there a general sufficient condition to guarantee that the set of $n$ "cyclicly permuted" vectors $\left\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n), (x_n, x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}), \ldots, (x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_1)\right\}$  is linearly independent?

When $n=2$ it is sufficient and necessary that $(x_1+x_2)(x_1-x_2)\ne0$.  When $n=3$, the determinant of the matrix whose rows are those vectors is $(x_1+x_2+x_3)\left(\frac{{(x_1-x_2)}^2+{(x_1-x_3)}^2+{(x_2-x_3)}^2}{2}\right)$, so the necessary and sufficient condition is that the sum of those $3$ numbers is not zero, and they are not all the same number.

In general, the determinant of the matrix is
$$
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{2\pi ik\ell}{n}}\cdot x_{\ell+1}\right).
$$
But I am unable to deduce some intuitive condition for that to be non-zero.

---

Since I think that determinant is a product of discrete Fourier transforms, I also tag this as related to Fourier transform.

If this is inappropriate, I will remove that tag.

---

P.S.

The determinant can be found as Lemma 5.26 in Washington's Introduction to cyclotomic fields.

---

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\sum x_k\ne0$ is always necessary; if $n$ is even then $\sum (-1)^k x_k\ne0$ is also necessary. It's also necessary that $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is not a nontrivial cyclic permutation of itself, in other words, that there does not exist $d\mid n$ such that $x_{k+d}=x_k$ always. One might speculate that these are the only necessary conditions. (The answer is probably simpler over the complex numbers, $-1$ is the only nontrivial root of unity in $\Bbb R$, which explains its appearance.)

Comment: I think that when $n$ is prime then your answer (but not proof?) for $n=3$ generalises. This is a special case of @GregMartin's conjecture. I think one can come at this by looking at the action of the GG of the rou over the field $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\dots, x_n)$.

Comment: I don't think there is any "intuitive" condition. Let's take $n=5$, and take $x_3,x_4,x_5$ arbitrary reals. Let $\beta=e^{2\pi i/5}$. Since $\{1,\beta\}$ is a linearly independent set over the reals, it's a basis for the complex numbers over the reals, so there exist reals $x_1,x_2$ such that $x_1+x_2\beta=-(x_3\beta^2+x_4\beta^3+x_5\beta^4)$, and you get determinant zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Your argument shows that for any three numbers there is a unique pair of numbers such that the determinant is zero, but we don't know about the relation between these five numbers, except that the "Fourier transform" is zero.  What I am asking is if there is a condition to determine when that "Fourier transform" is zero.  Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @ancientmathematician I will happily accept it as an answer if a proof of GregMartin's conjecture is provided.  :)

Comment: @GregMartin This is an interesting conjecture!  Thanks for that!

Comment: We know there is no relation between the three numbers $x_3,x_4,x_5$, as they are arbitrary, and doesn't that mean there's nothing relating the five numbers other than $x_1+x_2\beta+x_3\beta^2+x_4\beta^3+x_5\beta^4=0$? I think this argument shows that it's not enough to avoid the situations given by @Greg.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I see what you mean now.  But your argument also works for $n=3$, and in that case there is a good condition, so I still have hope.  ;P

Comment: @awllower For the alternating sum case: Let $(v_j)_j$ be the $n$ vectors considered. Then if $n$ is even, consider $\sum_j (-1)^jv_j$. Each coordinate of that becomes $\pm\sum_k (-1)^k x_k$.

Comment: @Milten Thanks for the help. I now see how to see the alternating sum being zero: take $k=n/2$.

Comment: When $n=3$, there's only one degree of freedom. Once you fix $x_1$, that fixes $x_2$ and $x_3$, so there's a formula for them in terms of $x_1$. That argument fails badly for $n=5$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Surely (at least when the $x_i$ are real transcendentals) from one relation $x_1+x_2\beta+\dots=0$ we get (by applying the automorphisms $\beta\mapsto\beta^j$)   three other relations, and then see that the $x_i$ are all equal?

Comment: @anc, no, you can see that $x_3,x_4,x_5$ are arbitrary reals from the argument I gave. Your automorphisms are over the rationals, that is, they fix the rationals, but there's no way to extend them to general reals.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Thanks. Confused myself there. My argument only works over the rationals for $n=p$.

Comment: @GregMartin Have you any idea whether your "conjecture" (if that's not too strong a word) holds over the rationals in the case $n=105$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson has correctly broken my "conjecture"! One simple counterexample that comes from his construction is the vector $(\phi,-1,\phi,0,0)$ where $\phi=\frac12(\sqrt5+1)$ is the golden ratio; its set of 5 cyclic permutations spans a real vector space of dimension only 3.

Comment: I'm guessing it might be helpful to look at the irreducible real representations of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, which would probably be the trivial representation, the sign representation if $n$ is even, and then direct sums of the complex $k$ and $-k$ representations otherwise.  I guess the corresponding basis vectors of the decompositions would be $[ \cos(2\pi k \ell/n) ]_{\ell=0}^{n-1}$ and $[ \sin(2\pi k \ell/n) ]_{\ell=0}^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sufficient condition is that one of the elements dominates the others.
Namely, for some $i\in[n]$, $|x_i|> \sum_{j\neq i}|x_{j}|$.
Note that we can choose the matrix to have only $x_i$ on its diagonal entries.
Then, our matrix is *strictly diagonally dominant*, making it non-singular.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I will wait to see if there are better answers for a while, before accepting the answer.  Thanks again.  :)